# Inner Join doesn't work well

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to get the town (`Localidad`) from referees(`ArbPrin, ArbAux, Anotador, Crono, Op24`). I make the query and the result isn't correct. Per example if I only have `ArbPrin` and `Anotador` it returns the town of `ArbPrin` for all the referees. If `ArbPrin` is from Malaga and `Anotador` is from Torremolinos, the result is Malaga for all the referees.

This is the query:

```
SELECT L1.Nombre AS'LocPrin', L2.Nombre AS'LocAux', L3.Nombre AS'LocAn',
L4.Nombre AS'LocCro', L5.Nombre AS'LocOp' FROM PARTIDO 
    INNER JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A1 ON PARTIDO.ArbPrin=A1.Codigo_arbitro
    INNER JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A2 ON PARTIDO.ArbPrin=A2.Codigo_arbitro 
    INNER JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A3 ON PARTIDO.ArbPrin=A3.Codigo_arbitro 
    INNER JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A4 ON PARTIDO.ArbPrin=A4.Codigo_arbitro 
    INNER JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A5 ON PARTIDO.ArbPrin=A5.Codigo_arbitro
    INNER JOIN LOCALIDAD L1 ON A1.Cod_localidad=L1.Codigo_localidad
    INNER JOIN LOCALIDAD L2 ON A2.Cod_localidad=L2.Codigo_localidad
    INNER JOIN LOCALIDAD L3 ON A3.Cod_localidad=L3.Codigo_localidad
    INNER JOIN LOCALIDAD L4 ON A4.Cod_localidad=L4.Codigo_localidad
    INNER JOIN LOCALIDAD L5 ON A5.Cod_localidad=L5.Codigo_localidad;
```

Here an example of the result. If I have the follows referees:

> ArbPrin: Malaga, ArbAux: Torremolinos, Anotador: Benalmadena

The result is the next:

```
LocPrin    LocAux    LocAn    LocCro    LocOp
-----------------------------------------------
Malaga     Malaga    Malaga   Malaga    Malaga
```

The result I want is the next:

```
LocPrin    LocAux         LocAn        LocCro    LocOp
--------------------------------------------------------
Malaga   Torremolinos   Benalmadena
```

Comment: why you joining same table multiple times , any reason

Comment: share what result set you are getting and what you want.

Comment: because it references differents fields.

Comment: I've edited the post with the result.

Comment: You're selecing the same field from the same table joined on the same field, why do you expect to get different names in the 3 columns you have? Maybe you need to show more details so that somebody is able to help

Comment: could you post an example on http://sqlfiddle.com/, to play with it?

Comment: I build it now. [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13c6f2)

Comment: check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13c6f2/2 I just changed how you join with `PARTIDO`. You were always joining on the first field which in your fiddle contains 1, so it is logical you get the same name every where. I Joined once on the first field, then on the second field, then on the 3rd field.

Comment: (A question featuring code, input data, expected output _and_ a SQL Fiddle - great stuff! +1)

Comment: Also: NORMALIZE your data

Comment: @Strawberry no, it's basketball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT L1.Nombre AS'LocPrin', L2.Nombre AS'LocAux', L3.Nombre AS'LocAn',
L4.Nombre AS'LocCro', L5.Nombre AS'LocOp' FROM PARTIDO 
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A1 ON PARTIDO.ArbPrin=A1.Codigo_arbitro
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A2 ON PARTIDO.ArbAux=A2.Codigo_arbitro 
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A3 ON PARTIDO.Anotador=A3.Codigo_arbitro 
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A4 ON PARTIDO.Crono=A4.Codigo_arbitro 
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A5 ON PARTIDO.Op24=A5.Codigo_arbitro
    LEFT JOIN LOCALIDAD L1 ON A1.Cod_localidad=L1.Codigo_localidad
    LEFT JOIN LOCALIDAD L2 ON A2.Cod_localidad=L2.Codigo_localidad
    LEFT JOIN LOCALIDAD L3 ON A3.Cod_localidad=L3.Codigo_localidad
    LEFT JOIN LOCALIDAD L4 ON A4.Cod_localidad=L4.Codigo_localidad
    LEFT JOIN LOCALIDAD L5 ON A5.Cod_localidad=L5.Codigo_localidad;
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13c6f2/4)**

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this is that, where a join column in `PARTIDO` is non-nullable (assuming there are some), the corresponding join could be made `FULL` rather than `LEFT`. This might gain a bit of performance. +1

Comment: @halfer feel free to edit my answer, or answer and I'll delete mine and learn something new. thanks for the +1

Comment: No - it's only a minor issue, and you've done all the hard work anyway `:)`